# Why does the number of fixed points changes when I change the dimension of the system?

Tags: programming

we define the following three dimensional system:

```
dyn3={b + r Subscript[\[Gamma], r] - s (b + Subscript[\[Gamma], s]) + 
  i s (-\[Beta] + \[Delta]), -b + s \[Beta] + 
  r Subscript[\[Beta], 
   r] - \[Gamma] + (-1 + i) \[Delta], -i r Subscript[\[Beta], r] + 
  i \[Gamma] - r (b + Subscript[\[Gamma], r]) + 
  s Subscript[\[Gamma], s] + i r \[Delta]}
```

which can be reduced to the following two dimensional system

```
dyn2={b - (-1 + i + s) Subscript[\[Gamma], r] - 
  s (b + Subscript[\[Gamma], s]) + i s (-\[Beta] + \[Delta]), -b + 
  s (\[Beta] - Subscript[\[Beta], r]) + Subscript[\[Beta], r] - 
  i Subscript[\[Beta], r] - \[Gamma] + (-1 + i) \[Delta]}
```

Now, solving the two systems yields a different number of solutions:

```
Solve[Thread[(dyn3)==0],{s,i,r}]
Solve[Thread[(dyn2)]==0,{s,i}]
```

I was expecting to get the same number of solutions. Could someone clarify what is the problem precisely in my code? Thank you!

Comment: How do you know that dyn3 reduces to dyn2 ? Did you solve for `r` to get there ? If so how ?

Comment: Dear userrandrand, 
 The r is eliminated using the equation : r=1-s-i, since dyn3 is invariant; (i.e. Its sum is (-1 + i + r + s) (-b + i \[Delta]))

Comment: If you are sure that dyn3 is equivalent to dyn2 then you might want to use `Reduce` and include all assumptions you have about the variables

Comment: Without any assumptions `Reduce` takes a long time with dyn3

Comment: You should also remove the subscripts. `Reduce` seems to have trouble with them

Comment: You can use for example `Reduce[Thread[dyn2 == 0] /. Subscript[\[Gamma], r] -> \[Gamma]r /. 
    Subscript[\[Gamma], s] -> \[Gamma]s /. 
   Subscript[\[Beta], r] -> \[Beta]r, {r, i, s}];`

Comment: In general `Subscript` leads to issues and should probably reserved to formatting using `Format`

Comment: Thanks, But I still have the same problem. I used the following numerical condition {b -> 1/16, \[Beta] -> 5/4, Subscript[\[Gamma], r] -> 1, 
 Subscript[\[Beta], r] -> 2, \[Gamma] -> 1/8, 
 Subscript[\[Gamma], s] -> 1, \[Delta] -> 1}., and execute using Reduce and the condition on the positivity of variables, and still have different number of solutions for dyn2==0 and dyn3==0.

Comment: What same problem ? The outputs of Reduce and Solve are different and `Reduce` gives a much lengthier output. Did you already set up all the conditions on the variables and turned them to rules to compare the outputs ?

Comment: I did not try but you might also want to use `LinearSolve`. The problem seems linear.

Comment: You might want to use `CoefficientArrays` to get the matrix as in the applications section of CoefficientArrays

Comment: The reason is that one of the three solutions does not satisfy the relation `r+i+s==1`. So when you impose that condition, you knock out a solution.

Comment: Precisely, Thanks!

Comment: found this thread while looking for something else. I should mention that perhaps my previous claim that there was a problem with Reduce and Subscript might have been linked to using both variables with and without subscripts in my notebook. I might have used Reduce with both but I do not know really.